# PowerShell cmdlet CommandRuntime WriteProgress line returns and tabs

Tags: c#, powershell

I am creating a PowerShell cmdlet where I use the CommandRuntime to write information to the terminal, and I use `CommandRuntime.WriteProgress(progressRecord)` to write progress information in an overlay that looks something like [this](http://i.technet.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC413420.jpg).  I create a ProgressRecord as such

```
ProgressRecord progressRecord = new ProgressRecord(activityId, activity, statusDescription);
```

and the current operation with

```
progressRecord.CurrentOperation = string.Format("Name\tDate\tTime\n{0}\t{1}\t{2}", name, date, time);
```

This last line is what is causing me trouble. My goal is to create a table of sorts, with Name Date and Time as headings separated by tabs and their appropriate variables shown underneath after a line return.  However, the tab and newline escapes do not show up correctly when this cmdlet is run in PowerShell, they just show odd circle like symbols. I have also tried using `t and `n, as I have seen these described as escapes for PowerShell scripts, but they just show up as plain text.

TL;DR Does anyone know how to insert tabs and newlines within a cmdlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backtick is the double quoted string escape character.

```
write-host "Hi`tKevin`n"
```

They don't work within single quotes. I just tried `n and `t with double quotes in write-progress and I see the funny face for the tab, so I can tell they are interpreted correctly

So this means tab and newline don't behave as you want them to within write-progress.

I did verify that the -status and -currentoperation strings will wrap if they are long enough. YOu could use wrapping to achieve the look of a table. But that means you're script is dependent on what environment is hosting Powershell.

From the command line version PS, you can set these:

```
$host.ui.RawUI.BufferSize.Width=80
$host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width=80
```

but it doesn't have any effect. You could run mode.exe:

```
mode con: cols=80
```

which works. Neither works in psISE.

```
$host.ui.rawui|gm # in powershell.exe
```

Shows that there are methods to directly access the screen buffer. You could put together you own script to show progress, using those methods. This would also be a powershell host specific solution.